# Grey out Woocommerce product variation based on conditions?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've got a customized WooCommerce shop where I want to be able to grey out certain product variations based on conditions, but I'm not sure where in the code to do it.

- I have two prices for each item, one is a member price and one is a retail price.
- I want everyone to see each variation but not be able to select the one that isn't available to them, so that non-members can see the retail price but can't select it, and vice versa.
- The other customization I want is the following:  I want to be able to only allow members to buy 5 products at member price per month, and then it will switch them over to retail price, so I need to be able to grey out the member price for members based on certain conditions as well.

Can anyone point me to the files/hooks/actions where I can inject some custom code into the variation output so I can make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your two questions you can use in a different way **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`** filter hook. With some conditions based on your users roles and on existing function arguments, customer will be able to select a variation of your product, but will not be able to added it to cart, if he is not allowed. You can even display a notice when customer try to add something when is not allowed…

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
function custom_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations ) {

    // Your code goes here

    // If $passed is set to "false", the product is not added
    // $passed = false;

    return $passed;
}
```

For your last question, you will need to set/update some custom user meta data regarding the 5 products by month for the members, each time they place an order. You can use for this the **`woocommerce_thankyou`** or **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** action hooks to set that custom data in the user meta data. Then you will be able to check this data enabling or disabling the right product variation in the **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`** filter hook.

To finish, if you really want to grey out some variations, you will have to use Javascript/jQuery, but is going to be quite difficult as there is already a lot of javascript/Ajax WooCommerce events on product variations, that will conflict yours. But in WooCommerce everything is possible depending on time and skills…